# Error: The method 'add' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: add("Test"), In flutter map

Tags: flutter, dart, null

There is a Dismissible widget that has a function to 'undo' the item map deletion. When I Dismiss an item that is not the last from you key on the map, it works fine, but when the item is the last item of your key it throws this error:

> The method 'add' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: add("Test")

**This is the code:**

```dart
return Dismissible(
      key: Key(event),
      child: ....my child
      onDismissed: (direction) {

        setState(() {
          _events[_thisDay].remove(event);
          if(_events[_thisDay].length == 0){
            _events.remove(_day);
          }
        });


        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            "Event $event dismissed !"),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: "Undo",
            onPressed: () => setState(() =>_events[_thisDay].add(event))), // HERE
        ));
      },
      background: Container(color: Colors.red),
    );
```

**How can I treat this error? *_events is null. _thisDay isn't**

Comment: First of all, in order to prevent the error you can use `null` check (`_events[_thisDay]?.add(event)`) before adding `event` to your list. Then, you have to check why is `_events[_thisDay]` null?

Comment: Is null because there are nothing inside.. When I remove all the elements from a map it is null and doesnt accept the add method, so, how could I add on it

Comment: Please tell me what type of key,value pair have you stored in `_events`?

Comment: DateTime: String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for `null` & then initialize `_events[_thisDay]` to an empty `Map`. Your code should look something like this:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        "Event $event dismissed !"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: "Undo",
        onPressed: () { 
          setState(() {
            _events[_thisDay] ??= <DateTime, String>{}; // if null, will be assigned to an empty map
            _events[_thisDay].add(event);
          });
        }),
    ));
```

Comment: Okay, please add `_events`, `_thisDay` & `event` variables in your question.